# Displaying JSON values in Angular2

Tags: json, angular

I'm testing out writing a simple application in Angular2 to display the weather of a city. I've created a service to retrieve JSON data from OpenWeatherMap when a user types in a city and submits a form. Inside my service, I have:

```
getDummyWeather() {
    return {"weather":{"main":"nice and sunny!"}};
}
```

I have the data stored as a JSON object called `weather` in my component. I figured that the call inside my template to get main's string would be `{{weather.weather.main}}` but then I get errors stating that the value `main` cannot be retrieved from undefined. Obviously, it's undefined until I submit the form. When I submit the form, nothing happens. So then I tried `{{weather.main}}` and I do not receive any errors, but I don't get any data back either. If I stringify the JSON, I get the full JSON string to display on form submit. Using `{{weather}}` displays [Object object] on form submit.

How do I get data from a JSON object to display in my template in Angular2?

Comment: [Object, object] is displayed when angular2 tries to interpolate an object.  Run your variable through JSON.stringify() to convert your json object to a string.  Then try to interpolate that value into the view.  This should help you debug what is actually happening in your view.

Comment: The issue is with nested json objects. I am now able to get values from JSON like `{"weather":"Nice and sunny"}` by using `{{weather.weather}}`. I cannot get JSON from the sample JSON in my question above because of the nesting.

Comment: In case Google leads to this site when searching for debugging json variables. `{{variable | json}}` is the answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the weather isn't available until you submit the form, then you shouldn't try displaying it until you know it's there:

```
<div *ngIf="weather.weather">{{ weather.weather.main }}</div>
```

If you really want to display it even if weather.weather is undefined, then you can use the safe navigation operator (also known as Elvis operator ) `?.`:

```
{{ weather.weather?.main }}
```